# My Android 7 tablet keep display restart / shutdown message and then restart itself

Tags: security, reboot, debug

I have a tablet with Android 7 that suddenly display restart or shutdown prompt message and when I click anywhere in the screen the message disappear then appear again then it restart itself. Is this hacking or software problem ?

Comment: Sounds more like a defect power button which is permanently triggered.